# Cerberus throwing exception when using added rule set

Tags: python, python-3.x, cerberus

I have the following piece in a Cerberus 1.3.2 schema (that I'm storing as a YAML file):

```
members:
    dependencies:
      res_type: gsuite_group
    type: dict
    keysrules:
      allowed:
        - gsuite
        - csod
    schema: gsuite_group_schema
```

As the rules I'm using for `members` are reused in other parts of the schema, I've tried isolating them into their own rule set:

```
rules_set_registry.add('gsuite_group_ruleset', {
    'dependencies': {'res_type': 'gsuite_group'},
    'type': 'dict',
    'keysrules': {'allowed': ['gsuite', 'csod']},
    'schema': 'gsuite_group_schema'}
)
```

I then change the `members` bit into:

```
members: gsuite_group_ruleset
```

Doing all of this and calling `validator.validate()` results in the following exception:

```
File "C:\Users\goncalo.lourenco\.virtualenvs\User_Sync-Zf6-tVvH\lib\site-packages\cerberus\validator.py", line 1440, in __validate_schema_mapping
  allow_unknown = self.schema[field].get('allow_unknown', self.allow_unknown)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a rules set as constraint to the `schema` rule, but it requires a full  schema of which the top level keys are key references, not keys.